# Open Password Protected MS ACCESS database in QT c++

Tags: c++, qt, ms-access

I am working on a QT C++ project in which I am using MS ACCESS as my database. I want to protect it with password and use it in my project.
I have used it without password but Now want to encrypt it with password for security.
Can Anyone guide me how to open password protected MS Access database in my QT Application?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to use ODBC for that. Lookup the syntax for the connection string for ODBC, and use that.

Comment: I am currently using ODBC connection with access file without password. Now I want to use password and I am looking for the connection string for that. If you know any resource please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
                         "DBQ=C:/db.accdb;Exclusive=1;Pwd=bjs}